# Filtering checkbox-list in a ReactiveForm leads to rendering error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-pipe

I have set up a reactive form. It includes regular input fields as well as multiple checkboxes as a list. I included also an input field to filter the checkbox list. While normal characters do not cause any problems, the dot (.) character seems to influence the rendering of the checkboxes.

If you search for "Zwei" everything seems fine. The (checked) checkboxes keep their "checked"-state, even if you delete the search value afterwards.

If you enter now "i.null" in the search field also everything seems OK. Now delete the first two characters and re-enter them; now a (rendering?) problem occurs. The second checkbox ("ZWEI.NULL") is rendered as "checked", but i wasn´t clicked neither marked as "selected" in the controller. If you take a look in the formGroup-debug-console message (by pressing the top button) the "selected"-property is not defined as "true".

Code example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuohtg

I expect the checkboxes to keep their checked-state. Do you have any ideas how this effect comes to play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core issue is the fact that you are using 2 different arrays in your component: one is the *controls* array in the `FormArray` instance (lets call it *ModelArray*) and the one returned after the filter is processed (lets call it *ViewArray*).

They both have the same `FormGroup` instances, but in different orders. You use *ViewArray* to generate your view and you map its indexes through the `FormArrayName` and `FormGroupName` directives to elements in the *ModelArray*.

For an index *I* with *0 < I < len(ViewArray)*,  you will end up displaying the values of a `FormGroup` instance *A <= ViewArray[I]* and binding the view inputs to an instance *B <= ModelArray[I]*, with the possibility of *A is B === false*

You can overcome this by binding the `FormGroup` instances to the `FormArrayName` by using the `FormGroupDirective` instead of the `FormGroupName` directive as follows:

```
<div class="form-group"
         formArrayName="permissions">
        <label class="checkboxLabel"
               *ngFor="let permissionGroup of permissionsControl.controls | LockFilter: filter.value; index as i"
               [formGroup]="permissionGroup">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   formControlName="selected">
            ({{ i }}){{permissionGroup.value.label}} ({{permissionGroup.value.id}})
        </label>
    </div>
```

A working example can be found [in this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-issue)

Comment: Indeed, didn't notice that !

Comment: Hmm, that sounds logical. Thanks for the explanation and your working demo! Im going to implement this in my production code and test it there as well. *thumbsUp*

Comment: @juli consider to mark this as answer if it solved your issue